# Listar dias da semana atual com PHP

Tags: php, data

Tenho que fazer um calendário com PHP e praticamente está pronto, o problema só está que por exemplo, no dia de hoje (**28/07/2016**) a semana no calendário começa em **01/08/2016** e o certo deveria ser **25/07/2016** até **29/07/2016** (segunda a sexta-feira).

Tenho a função abaixo:

```
<?php
public function DataSemana($semana = 1){

        $c = time() + 60*60*24*5*$semana;
        $date = date('Y-m-d', $c);
        $dayofweek = date('w', strtotime($date));
        $result    = strtotime((0-$dayofweek+1).' day', strtotime($date));

        $primeira_data = date('Y-m-d', $result);
        $segunda_data = date('Y-m-d', $result+(60*60*24*5));

        $inicio = new DateTime($primeira_data);
        $fim = new DateTime($segunda_data);

        //sequencia aritmetica com razao igual a 1 dia
        $intervalo = new DateInterval('P1D');

        $datas = new DatePeriod($inicio, $intervalo, $fim);

        return $datas;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Você está levando em consideração que a resposta do domingo no `date('w')` é 6? O primeiro dia da semana, pro PHP, é Segunda.

Comment: Como poderia fazer para iniciar da semana que estou ? de seg a sexta ? @WilliamAparecidoBrandino

Comment: Primeiro, tentando entender porque já deixa fixo o parâmetro de segunda feira no recebimento da tua função. Ele sempre vai buscar a próxima segunda feira. A meu ver, a lógica deve ser buscar o dia da semana da data atual, e usar as funções para buscar a segunda feira correspondente.